# How to reorder divs using flex box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to keep a seo friendly and semantic structure for my DOM, without repeating whole elements to display them in various positions.

My layout is based on `display: flex` items. I try to achieve the following:

[image: Preview of mobile and desktop layout]

Important things to know:

- I do not want to show/hide divs based on the window width (to avoid unnecessary duplicates)
- None of the divs has a known or fixed height
- **On desktops** the divs should be vertical centered, while the right column builds a tag-team (behaves like one single div)
- The layout needs to support at least IE11+

Is there a css only solution to achieve this?

If not, it would be easy to cut out the green div and paste its content into the pink one using javascript. But I do have concerns about the performance and "flickering" using this, although resizing the browser makes it more complicated. Do I make this needlessly complicated?

Here is fiddle showing a **working solution but with javascript**:

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](https://codepen.io/marianrick/pen/wqxVOg?editors=1010)

Comment: Flexbox has an `order` property for exactly this purpose. If you want a div that's second in your HTML to show up on top, you can just do `order: 1` for that div in your CSS.

Comment: Basically, this is **very** difficult if not impossible with flexbox. Any required properties are not supported in many browsers. CSS Grid could *possibly* be an option .

Comment: @cjl750 thanks for the hint. If you read carefully or checkout the demo (where I have used this) you will see, that this does not solve the problem, while it can be a start to solve it.

Comment: @Paulie_D a problem about CSS grids is, that very often they do work with `float`s. Using floats this is easy to achieve, while you need to define one object as the "higher" one. If I am not able to do this, I think its hard to find a working floating solution… than it will be javascript I guess.

Comment: CSS Grid has **nothing** to do with `float`. It's an *entirely* dfferent layout method...hence the capital "G".

Comment: Aaah, thanks @Paulie_D. I misunderstood you. I will try to dig into CSS Grid, it seems to be very interesting.

Comment: With flex, you are looking at show/hiding at least one section. If you reorder the design a bit then it will be easy to achieve. I usually inform my design team which tech we are using and what we can and cannot do to avoid situations like these

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "I do not want to show/hide divs based on the window width" but I was thinking of suggesting media queries

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao OP means to not have duplicated content and show/hide with media queries

Comment: @Huangism Will be really interesting to see this implemented in pure css without media queries

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao it needs media query but OP does not want to duplicate content

Comment: As Paulie_D pointed our, css Grid is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

In general, you can't do this with Flexbox alone, though there might be a compromise based on each given case.

With Flexbox alone, using fixed height, you can accomplish this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  height: 90vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.flex div {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}
.flex div:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}
.flex::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .flex div {
    width: auto;
  }
  .flex::before {
    display: none;
  }
 .flex div:nth-child(2) {
    order: 0;
  }
}


/*  styling  */
.flex-child {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(1) {
  background: #e6007e;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f4997c;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(3) {
  background: #86c06b;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Top/Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Center/Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Bottom/Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, where no fixed height is allowed, you can combine Flexbox and `float`.

By set up it for mobile using Flexbox where you add the *center* item first in the markup and then, with `order`, move it between the *top* and *bottom*.

With a media query you then simply make the *flex container* a block element and use `float` to position the *left* to the left and the *right* to the right.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  height: 90vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5%;
  flex-basis: 33.333%;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-child:nth-child(1) {
  background: #e6007e;
  order: 1;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f4997c;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(3) {
  background: #86c06b;
  order: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex {
    display: block;
  }
  .flex-child {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .flex-child:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .flex-child:nth-child(2),
  .flex-child:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Center/Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Top/Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Bottom/Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Update

Here is another version combining Flexbox with `position: absolute`, which also vertically center the items in *desktop mode*

*Updated, added a script to control so the absolute positioned element won't get bigger than the right items, and if so, adjust the flex containers height.*

*Note, the script is by no means optimized, it is only there to show how a fix in certain situations*

```js
(function() {

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);

  var fp = document.querySelector('.flex');
  var fi = fp.querySelector('.flex-child:nth-child(1)');
  var resizeTimeout;
  function resizeThrottler() {
    // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in the queue
    if ( !resizeTimeout ) {
      resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeTimeout = null;
        actualResizeHandler();
     
       // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
       }, 66);
    }
  }

  function actualResizeHandler() {
    // handle the resize event
    if (fp.offsetHeight <= fi.offsetHeight) {
      fp.style.cssText = 'height: '+fi.offsetHeight+'px';
    } else {
      fp.style.cssText = 'height: auto';
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    actualResizeHandler();
  })
  
}());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  height: 90vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5%;
}

.flex-child:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(3) {
  order: 2;
}

.flex-child:nth-child(1) div {
  background: #e6007e;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(2) div {
  background: #f4997c;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(3) div {
  background: #86c06b;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .flex-child {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .flex-child:nth-child(1) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .flex-child:nth-child(n+2) {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Center/Left<br>with more<br>content<br>than any<br>of the<br>other items<br>other items<br>other items<br>other items<br>other items</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Top/Right<br>with more<br>content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div>Bottom/Right<br>with more</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

With script one can also reorder/move items between elements.

Stack snippet

*You can also combine this with a media query, and use it to do the actual re-order of the elements*

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($( window ).width() < 600 ) {
      $(".one").insertBefore("#b");
    } else {
      $(".one").insertBefore(".two");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.outer, #flex, #flex2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#a {
  order: 4;
  background: #ccc;
}
#b {
  order: 1;
  background: #aaa;
}
#c {
  order: 3;
  background: #d33;
}
.one {
  order: 2;
  background: #aaa;
}
.two {
  order: 5;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  <div id="flex">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
  </div>

  <div id="flex2">
    <div class="one">Show me 2nd</div>
    <div class="two">Show me 5th</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Update 2 (answered [at another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383140/making-two-adjacent-elements-behave-like-a-single-element) but later moved here)

If we talk about smaller items, like a header or smaller menus, one can do what many website platform providers like "squarespace", "weebly", "wordpress", etc does. Their templates holds different markup structures, where an item sometimes exist twice, one visible for desktop, another for mobile.

Also, being so small, there will be less to nothing when it comes to performance (and personally I don't see anymore issue with this than having duplicate CSS rules, one for each screen size, and happily do this instead of introducing script).

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9o16dxhx/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  width: 50%;
}
.container div:nth-child(-n+2) {
  border: dashed;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;                                  /*  hide outer "Flower"  */
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container div {
    width: auto;
  }
 .container div:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;                               /*  show outer "Flower"  */
  }
  .container div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;                                /*  hide inner "Flower"  */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Flower</div>
  <div>Tree</div>
  <div>
    <div>Flower</div>
    <div>Bee</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. While this code does work with fixed heights (`50%`), it does not accomplish the same with a not known height. Thats the problem about using `float` as a solution. The part of centering it vertical without a known height is important in my case.

Comment: @MarianRick I updated so it centers in _desktop mode_ ... btw, did you down vote??

Comment: thanks again. As I have tried to imply in the image, its not about centering the content of each div in the right column. It is about centering both of the divs "as a tag-team". So that they behave as one single div, which is being vertical aligned with the left div. Thats why there is white space above the pink and below the green div. Do you get me or should I create an example?

Comment: yes. Not to harm or offend you, but to save the quality of this sites content. Currently your solution solves another problem than asked in the question. Of course I will change this, if it targets the exact problem stated out in the question. There is a working demo using javascript inside this codepen. I start to question, if its possible without js: https://codepen.io/marianrick/pen/wqxVOg?editors=1010

Comment: @MarianRick Well, when someone is actively working to help you, downvoting is a bad way to say _thank you for helping me_. When I stopped asking and improving, and left you with a non working solution I can understand...still, when someone help you in any way, I find it very difficult to understand a down vote....

Comment: I did not mean to offend you and try to show my appreciation in the comments by being kind and thankful. At the same time, I see that there are a lot of users upvoting your answer, while it does not solve the problem. Thats not your fault, but kind of dangerous, as its somehow a "misinformation". Thats why I think its important to down vote. Of course its important to check edited answers to undo these down votes.

Comment: thanks for your updated suggestion. This still has some problems. Imagine, that there is no given height for the parent container. Next, the left column has less content, then the right one. In this case, there will be caused a unwanted overlay of the `position: absolute` element over some content that may appear before or after the parent container.

As I have thought about some of your concepts as well, I think, that the only possible solution is using CSS Grid or javascript to achieve this.

Comment: @MarianRick From start a solution using Flexbox and no script would be a compromise based on the given case. Now when you change the initial question's requirements, you invalidate my answer little by little, which is not okay. In such cases one accept the given answer and post a new question. .... That said, no, there will always be cases where Flexbox and CSS alone can't solve an issue, and with the extra requirements it can't. CSS Grid can, and script can, so I updated my answer with a script

Comment: @MarianRick For a CSS Grid solution, and to not invalidate my answer completely, reword and post a new question, and tag it with `css-grid` and you will get an answer with that. And since mine now solve your question an accept/upvote would feel great