# Bootstrap order and col below

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm strugling with a bootstrap layout.

On mobile I have this layout (easy part):

```
Title
Image
Text
```

On desktop, I want this layout :

```
Image   Title
        Text
```

But the div title always have the image height. Impossible to put the text below it.
Will appreciate any help ! Thanks !

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 order-lg-2">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7 order-lg-1">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" lass="img-fluid" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 order-lg-3">
            <h3>Cyprum itidem insulam</h3>
            <p>procul a continenti discretam et portuosam inter municipia crebra urbes duae faciunt claram Salamis Post quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huiuPost quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huius modi scrutabatur. quae singula narrare non refert, me professione modum, quod evitandum est, excedamus.s modi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In addition of what @Paulie_D said, you could provide a jsFiddle on https://jsfiddle.net/. If it is viewable, it is easier to understand what the problem is you are having.

Comment: snippet added, thanks

Comment: That is not possible, unless you combine it with fixed heights or e.g. float ... something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883549/how-to-reorder-divs-using-flex-box

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using Bootstrap `class`. You can try this. I repeating **Order 3**. Check the snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 order-lg-2">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <div class="row hidden-lg-down">
                  <div class="col-12 order-lg-3">
                      <h3>Cyprum itidem insulam</h3>
                      <p>procul a continenti discretam et portuosam inter municipia crebra urbes duae faciunt claram Salamis Post quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huiuPost quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huius modi scrutabatur. quae singula narrare non refert, me professione modum, quod evitandum est, excedamus.s modi</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 order-lg-1">
                <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" lass="img-fluid" alt=""/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 hidden-lg-up order-lg-3">
            <h3>Cyprum itidem insulam</h3>
            <p>procul a continenti discretam et portuosam inter municipia crebra urbes duae faciunt claram Salamis Post quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huiuPost quorum necem nihilo lenius ferociens Gallus ut leo cadaveribus pastus multa huius modi scrutabatur. quae singula narrare non refert, me professione modum, quod evitandum est, excedamus.s modi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Note: Check this snippet in full width.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I prefer to avoid to duplicate content

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset classes in Bootstrap.

For example class `offset-0 offset-lg-5`.

Read the docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns).

Comment: It doesn't work with offset. The text content is always below the image

Comment: Finally I use your solution with personnal css. Thanks !