# Remove the space resulting from the row above with not equal height elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to  place description under the photo from 768px up, but without white gap between them. Could someone help me.

I note that the HTML order cannot be changed. Eventually element's can be wrapped.

I tried flexbox and grid layout but with no success.

Below is the latest version of what I am trying to achieve.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}
.container div {
  padding: 20px;
}
.container .name {
  background: orange;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container .name {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
.container .photo {
  background: yellow;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container .photo {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    padding: 100px 20px;
  }
}
.container .price {
  background: purple;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container .price {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    padding: 150px 20px;
  }
}
.container .description {
  background: blue;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="name">name</div>
      <div class="photo">photo</div>
      <div class="price">price</div>
      <div class="description">description</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The yellow expands if I remove `align-items: flex-start;`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to expand any of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883549/how-to-reorder-divs-using-flex-box

Comment: I don't think there is this same or similar situation.

Comment: If you, as showed in the suggested dupe link, combine float and Flexbox, you can achieve what you asked, hence it is called a duplicate. Simply put, it does not have to be an exact code of yours to be called a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reorder divs using flex box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883549/how-to-reorder-divs-using-flex-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need flexbox layout for that. A couple of good old-fashioned floats will do.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
}
.container div {
  padding: 20px;
}
.container .name {
  background: orange;
}
.container .photo {
  background: yellow;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container .photo {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 100px 20px;
  }
}
.container .price {
  background: purple;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container .price {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 150px 20px;
  }
}
.container .description {
  background: blue;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container .description {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="name">name</div>
      <div class="photo">photo</div>
      <div class="price">price</div>
      <div class="description">description</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```